# Generating ssh-key file for multiple users on each server

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have to create 60 ssh users on one of the servers. I created users using small user creation script which loops though each users from the user list. 
I'm trying to run the similar script which will generate sshkeys for each user.

```
#!/bin/sh
for u in `cat sshusers.txt
do
echo $u
sudo su - $u
mkdir .ssh; chmod 700 .ssh; cd .ssh; ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -t rsa -N '';
chmod 600 /home/$u/.ssh/*; 
cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
done
```

when i run this script, it basically logs into all 60 users account but does not create. ssh dir or generate passwordless ssh.key. Any idea to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`sudo su - $u` starts a new shell; the commands that follow aren't run until that shell exits. Instead, you need to run the commands with a single shell started by `sudo`.

```
while IFS= read -r u; do
    sudo -u "$u" sh -c "
      mkdir .ssh
      chmod 700 .ssh
      cd .ssh
      ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -t rsa -N ''
      chmod 600 '/home/$u/.ssh/'*
      cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
      "
done < sshusers.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Chepner. I just ran the scripts but i have getting permission denied error as below. mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.ssh’: Permission denied
chmod: cannot access ‘.ssh’: Permission denied
sh: line 3: cd: .ssh: Not a directory
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
open id_rsa failed: Permission denied.
Saving the key failed: id_rsa.
chmod: cannot access ‘/home/userid/.ssh/*’: No such file or directory
cp: failed to access ‘authorized_keys’: Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

After trying several times, i made little changes that seems to work now.

```
#!/bin/bash
for u in `more sshuser.txt`
do
echo $u
sudo su - "$u" sh -c "
  mkdir .ssh
  chmod 700 .ssh
  cd .ssh
  ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -t rsa -N ''
  chmod 600 '/home/$u/.ssh/'*
  cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys "

done
```